# Oracle procedure select data from table passing column from all_tab_columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want the procedure to return table data but the columns to be passed dynamically from all_tab_columns.

I want to select data from my_table but columns to be passed from all_tab_columns

Comment: OK what have you attempted?  look at EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and DBMS_SQL package.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you pass the table name as well and raise that "procedure's" usability? Here's one option: create a function which accepts table name and list of columns and returns refcursor.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_tab in varchar2, par_cols in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc   sys_refcursor;
  5    l_str  varchar2(1000);
  6  begin
  7    l_str := 'select ' || par_cols || ' from ' ||
  8              dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_tab);
  9    open l_rc for l_str;
 10    return l_rc;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test('dept', 'dname, loc') from dual;

F_TEST('DEPT','DNAME
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME          LOC
-------------- -------------
ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
RESEARCH       DALLAS
SALES          CHICAGO
OPERATIONS     BOSTON
Dept 1         NY
Dept 2         London

6 rows selected.


SQL>
```